# What are the small orange dots which appear next to a selected object

Tags: edit-mode

I have noticed ever since I first used Blender (mostly) when I select an object a small orange dot appears near to it and when I select All there are many of those small dots displayed (see image below - dots arrowed). Just wondering what they are called (so I can research it) and/or what they are used for.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: They appear to be the Object Origins for objects that are Selected but not the Active Object: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/origin.html

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will research 'object origin' point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are object origins.  Blender will show you only the origin of the currently selected objects. The sphere is the only selected object in this example:

[image: a cube and a sphere showing the origin of the sphere.]

If you select multiple objects, then you'll see multiple origins

[image: The cube and the sphere both selected]

By default the origin of the object is at the center of its geometry, but if you manipulate an object in edit mode, or you use commands to specifically move the origin, it can be anywhere.  Here I've moved the sphere in edit mode, leaving the origin in its original position:

[image: Sphere with moved origin]

There should be one dot for each object you have selected.  The color has to do with whether they're the *active* object or not.  Red means they're not.  Orange, as in my sphere example means they are.  If you look closely at the middle example, the origin of the cube is red, like your objects.

Comment: Thanks Marty. I have since found a video tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ojeeuNtJM8) which demonstrates how to move the origin which can be a great help if you say want to scale in one direction only on a particular axis which I think was also pointed out to me in a question I asked on how to move a face in one direction only (or something like that).