# Moving the actual cube (object) instead of the dot (?)

Tags: interface, transforms

I am not sure if I am using the right terminology, but I would like to understand how one can select to move the actual mesh object using the move tool?  (Instead of some sort of tiny dot pivot point?)

[image: Image from Gyazo]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164936/can-only-move-object-origin-in-object-mode-cant-move-the-mesh

Comment: @L0Lock that would only answer the question for someone who knew that the 'tiny dot pivot point' was the 'object origin', since the answer doesn't show the relationship to the origin, since the OP knew what the origin was.

Comment: nomenclature is hard for newbies. origin is called pivot in 3dsmax etc...  I think you guys should have a visual FAQ for newbies who are not sure what things are called.

Comment: @MartyFouts yes, so that's the answer. What is your point here?

Comment: @ina sure it's hard, but when you are a newbie: you don't know what you don't know. You don't know the name of anything that isn't named to you, you don't know that the manual exists and is full of explanation. And you wouldn't know that the first website you find to ask your questions has a visual FAQ that might or might not cover the issue that you are still unable to search for because of your lack of knowledge. Adding more and more resources that repeat each other isn't the solution. Guiding people towards what they need, is.

Comment: @L0Lock There is no way to tell from that answer what the phrase 'object origin' means.  If you don't already know that the yellow dot is the 'object origin' then that answer does not answer your question.  You need an answer that _does_ tell you that the yellow dot is the 'object origin'.  If you want to mark this question as a duplicate then it has to be a duplicate of a question that does have the definition in it.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234221/what-are-the-small-orange-dots-which-appear-next-to-a-selected-object https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129954/what-is-this-dot-not-fireflies-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot is the *Object Origin* and the behavior suggests that you have enabled an option:

[image: Options]

in particular, you seem to have enabled "Affect Only Origins".  To check this, go to the upper right corner of the 3D viewport and click on *Options* (highlighted in blue in the screenshot).  If *Origins* is checked, uncheck it.

Comment: thanks! I think you guys should have a visual FAQ for newbies who are not sure what things are called.

Comment: is there a way to easily center an origin on an object once you have moved it?

Comment: @Ina  Select the object, right click and select Set Origin -> Origin to Geometry.  The visual FAQ starts at the [Window System Introduction](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/introduction.html) page in the manual; but it only covers the bare minimum.